# I don't understand why this loop doesn't execute it's block

Tags: c

While playing with code in the following program I assumed that the star should be printed on screen but it exits the loop without printing anything. Why at least one star is not printing when it enters the loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,sum_sq=0, sq_sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<=10&&(sum_sq+=i*i)&&(sq_sum+=i);++i)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("%d",sq_sum*sq_sum - sum_sq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`((i<=10)&&(sum_sq+=i*i)&&(sq_sum+=i))` this condition is false. the output

> true && 0 && 0 = false;

finally, compiler identifies**false**. So the star is printed. U try mine below code.

int i,sum_sq=0, sq_sum=0;

```
for(i=0;((i<=10)&&(sum_sq+=(i+1)*(i+1))&&(sq_sum=i+2));++i)
{
    sum_sq += i*i;
    printf("%d ",sum_sq);
    sq_sum+=i;
    printf("%d ",sum_sq);
    printf(" *\n");
}
```

for loop every time if condtion true or false.

Comment: i meant control enters the loop without checking any condition it should print the star.